# especify width to concrete branches in a plot.phylo

Tags: r, tree, phylogeny

I want to mark different branches on a phylogenetic tree using 3 different line widths.
How can I especify that branch 2 has width= 2, line 10 has width= 4 and the remaining lines have width=1?
For example, there are 88 branches in the bird.orders dataset

```
data(bird.orders)
bird.orders@edge
```

This, obviously does not do anything

```
plot(bird.orders, edge.width = c(bird.orders$edge[2]==2, bird.orders$edge[10]==4, bird.orders$edge[-c(2,10)]==1))
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First you need to figure out the edge order, which apparently follows these rules when the argument direction of `plot.phylo()` is set `direction='leftwards'`:

1. go left up to the farthest branch tip (leaf)
2. then go right
3. then go down
4. each time a branch splits, repeat 1 to 3

Once obtained the map of the edges, one must build a vector with the desired widths for each branch. Wector position matches edge position. Using the example in this question, this code will make branches 1 to 5 to have width=4, the rest will take the default width (1):

```
plot(bird.orders, edge.width = c(4,4,4,4,4))
```